# Detemining time to screen for a web app

Tags: javascript, dom, web

A web application has certain timeliness constraints. How can I check the time from invocation of a JS function to having the information visible in the browser?

Clearly I can start a stopwatch, but on what event should I stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern browsers offer the [Navigation Timing API](http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/), which you can use to get this kind of information. Which information from it you use is up to you, probably [`domComplete`](http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#dom-performancetiming-domcomplete) or [`loadEventStart`](http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#dom-performancetiming-loadstart) (or, of course, `loadEventEnd` if you want to know when everything is fully loaded, but you could do that with `window.onload`). [This tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/basics/) may be useful.

If you're talking about requesting something via ajax after page load (you've said "...from invocation of a JS function to having the informatin visible in the browser..."), adding that to the page, and seeing how long that took, you'd stop the timer after you were done appending the elements to the DOM, immediately before returning from your ajax `onreadystatechange` handler callback. Or if you want to be *really* sure the information has been rendered, after using `setTimeout(function() { /*...end the timer...*/ }, 0);` from that callback instead, which yields back to the browser for the minimum possible time, giving it a chance to render (if it doesn't render while JS is running).